# Lista com os atributos que apresentam diferença entre os objetos - Java

Tags: java, objetos, comparação, hashmap, atributos

Estou precisando comparar dois objetos em *JAVA* de modo eu consiga obter um *MAP* com chave e valor dos atributos que apresentam diferença. Preciso dessa lógica para um objeto genérico, capaz de receber qualquer tipo.

**Ex:**

`OBJETO 1 - nome: João, email: joao@email.com, telefone: 1234-5678, endereco: rua123`

`OBJETO 2 - nome: João, email: joao12@email.com, telefone: 1234-5678, endereco: rua678`

Nesse exemplo teria um retorno de um Map, ou outra estrutura de dados como a seguir:

`{email: joao12@email.com,  endereco: rua 678}`

Alguem sabe de algum modo que eu possa estar fazendo isso? O Java apresenta alguma função que já realiza essa diferença?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes definir um custom comparator na tua estrutura de dados e aí implementares a comparação entre os dois objectos.

**Update:**

Pensava que queria ordenar numa estrutura de dados com base nas suas diferenças, mas parece que não é isso que quer fazer. Segundo entendi melhor quer apenas obter o atributo e seu valor dos campos diferentes de dois objectos. Creio que não existe nada em especifico que o Java ofereça. Pode desenvolver algo deste tipo:

```
public class Teste {

static class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String telefone;
    private String endereco;

    public Pessoa(String nome, String email, String telefone, String endereco) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
}

public static Map<String, String> getDiffs(Pessoa p1, Pessoa p2) {
    Map<String, String> diffs = new HashMap<>();
    if (!p1.getNome().equals(p2.getNome())) {
        diffs.put("nome", p2.getNome());
    }

    if (!p1.getEmail().equals(p2.getEmail())) {
        diffs.put("email", p2.getEmail());
    }

    if (!p1.getTelefone().equals(p2.getTelefone())) {
        diffs.put("telefone", p2.getTelefone());
    }

    if (!p1.getEndereco().equals(p2.getEndereco())) {
        diffs.put("endereco", p2.getEndereco());
    }

    return diffs;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("João", "joao@email.com", "1234-5678", "rua123");
    Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("João", "joao12@email.com", "1234-5678", "rua678");

    Map<String, String> diffs = getDiffs(p1, p2);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(diffs.entrySet().toArray()));
}

}
```

**Update2:**
Utilizando reflection.

```
public class Test {

static class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String telefone;
    private String endereco;

    public Pessoa(String nome, String email, String telefone, String endereco) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
}

public static Map<String, Object> getDiffs(Pessoa p1, Pessoa p2) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, Object> diffs = new HashMap<>();
    for (Field field : p1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        String fieldName = field.getName();
        Object fieldValue1 = field.get(p1);
        Object fieldValue2 = field.get(p2);
        if (!fieldValue1.equals(fieldValue2)) {
            diffs.put(fieldName, fieldValue2);
        }
    }

    return diffs;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("João", "joao@email.com", "1234-5678", "rua123");
    Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("João", "joao12@email.com", "1234-5678", "rua678");

    Map<String, Object> diffs = getDiffs(p1, p2);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(diffs.entrySet().toArray()));
}

}
```

Comment: Teria algum exemplo que pudesse me ajudar?

Comment: Atualizei a minha resposta. Veja se é isto que procura?

Comment: É exatamente isso, porém preciso de algo genérico, devido ao fato que poderei ter a comparação de vários tipos de objetos diferentes. E implementar essa diferença em cada modelo que tenho, seria algo muito penoso, tendo também muita redundancia de código.

Comment: Para esse caso a única forma que conheço é utilizando reflection. Tens de ter a conta os contras de utilizar essa abordagem e por isso aconselho a leres um pouco sobre isto. (atualizei o exemplo)

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava, porém consegui fazer de outro modo, utilizando as classes (Diff, DiffResult, DiffBuilder) do pacote builder do Apache Lang 3. Mas utilizei reflection conforme exemplificado aqui. Obrigado!